Looking for a martial arts children's movie from the late 90's
I'm looking for a movie I saw as a kid, but I can't remember anything specific about it :). However, I know that one of the main characters also played in the movie I am looking for now, here is what I can remember.

The main cast were three children, two boys one girl. The age ranged from around 12 (boy) to maybe 16/17 (girl).
It is staged during summer break and those three enlisted in a karate (or some other martial art) dojo.
The trainer (the guy I am looking for), was a big muscular guy with shoulder-long blond hair.
There is also a criminal organization, the leader of which has a kid who also practices martial arts.
At some point the children discover that their trainer fights this criminal organization (which in fact is some very old organization) while wearing a white mask (I think they called them dragon masks, but it could easily be something different).
There are three more of those masks, one is red another one is gold and the color of the last one I can't remember, I think black. The children will get those.
The fights in this movie have a humoristic touch to them.

I could maybe remember some other bits and pieces but I think it should be enough to identify it if you know it.

You're after Pocket Ninjas from 1994, riding on the coattails of movies like 3 Ninjas and Surf Ninjas.

The evil Cobra Khan rises from the underworld and begins polluting the environment. The White Dragon tries to stop him but is injured so must pass the job onto his three teenage students.

The three students are two boys and a girl and they receive masks in 3 colors: Red, gold and black. The blonde guy in question (The White Dragon) is Gary Daniels. Here's a (fan-made?) trailer:



